# Printing Int in struct prints address

Tags: c

I'm reading an algorithms book and I found myself stuck on this bit. I create a doubly linked list and when I try to print out its contents it prints out what I believe is address or some other value that is not relevant to what I want. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct double_element *dElement;
struct double_element
{
    int value;
    dElement prev;
    dElement next;
};

dElement createNewDListWithElements(int count)
{
    dElement element = malloc(sizeof(dElement));

    element->value = 1;
    element->next = NULL;
    element->prev = NULL;

    dElement previous = element;

    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {

        dElement el = malloc(sizeof(dElement));

        el->value = i;
        el->next = NULL;
        el->prev = previous;
        previous->next = el;

        previous = el;
    }

    return element;
}

void printDList(dElement node)
{
    printf("printing doubly linked list:\n");

    while (node) {

        printf("%i\n", node->value);

        node = node->next;
    }

    printf("end printing double linked list\n");
}
```

Here is the output:

```
printing doubly linked list:
1
1070320
1070336
1070352
1070368
1070384
1070400
1070416
1070432
1070448
end printing double linked list
```

Comment: Please post the code where you call `createNewDListWithElements(int count)`. And your code is good, the only observation is that I would check that `malloc()` didn't return `NULL` before dereferencing the pointers.

Comment: ... i.e. post a whole program that demonstrates this behavior that others can simply compile and run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to allocate space for a `struct double_element`, but you only ask for enough space to store a `struct double_element*`.

Comment: From what code did you end up with this conclusion?

Comment: @iharob  `typedef struct double_element *dElement; ... dElement el = malloc(sizeof(dElement));` --> `dElement el = malloc(sizeof( * el));`

Comment: I didn't understand the answer at first, it's not clear what it's trying to say, and yes it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are allocating space for a pointer instead of the struct itself, the reason the dangerous `typedef` of the pointer, if you want to guarantee the allocation is correct regardless of the `typedef`'s in your code you can do this

```
dElement element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
```

that would allocate space for the struct, just as if you had called

```
dElement element = malloc(sizeof(struct double_element));
```

you can see that the `typedef` is harmful, a pointer should be explicitly a pointer, so the correct way to write the code without falling in this kind of issue is

```
struct double_element *element = malloc(sizeof(struct double_element));
/*                    ^ don't skip this no matter what */
```

also, you should make clear what the struct names are and how you name your variables, you could for example use *CamelCase* for the struct names, and lower case with underscores for your variables, something like this

```
struct DoubleElement *element = ...
```

it would make it clear that `DoubleElement` is the name of a struct, and even though you can leave the `struct` instead of `tyepdef`ing it, because that makes it even clearer.